# Подскажите где найти, или как правильно называется)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как правильно называется слайдер с 4 картинками сразу, пишу карусель. Оно мне тонну слайдеров дает, но который мне надо, тяжело найти, или скиньте ссылок, кого не затруднит, заранее спасибо)

Comment: Название слайдера зависит от типа визуализации переключения, а не от кол-ва картинок.

Comment: У меня должно быть 4 картинки которые видно, и переключение стрелочками.

Comment: Это может почти любой слайдер.

Comment: 4 картинки -  это настройка слайдера, и да практически любого, и в настройках будет св-во что-то вроде `slidesToShow: 4`, например как [тут](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) в разделе примеров Multiple Items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видел подобное через [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) делали, получилось следующее:
[image: example]
Пример кода:

```js
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
 prevArrow: $('.prev'),
 nextArrow: $('.next'),
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```

```css
html {box-sizing: border-box;}
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: inherit;}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 padding: 5px;
}

h2 {
  text-align:center;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.slick-dots {
 text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    &.slick-active {
      button {
        background-color:black;
      }
    }
    button {
      font: 0/0 a;
      text-shadow: none;
      color: transparent;
      background-color:#999;
      border:none;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius:50%;
    }
  :hover{
   background-color: black;
  }
  }
}

/* Custom Arrow */
.prev{
 color: #999;
 position: absolute;
 top: 38%;
 left: -2em;
 font-size: 1.5em;
  :hover{
   cursor: pointer;
   color: black;
  }
}
.next{
 color: #999;
 position: absolute;
 top: 38%;
 right: -2em;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 :hover{
   cursor: pointer;
   color: black;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .next {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.5/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.5/slick.min.css"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Slider - Multpile Items & Responsive</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 heroSlider-fixed">
        <div class="overlay">
      </div>
         <!-- Slider -->
        <div class="slider responsive">
          <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
     </div>
        </div>
     <!-- control arrows -->
    <div class="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Пример выполняется не совсем верно, вот ссылка на правильно работающий пример и код: https://codepen.io/bkainteractive/pen/VLxLYp

Comment: Там работает, я копипастю а оно едет все

Comment: Значит не подключили что-то

Comment: все заработало))Спасибо большое)